# How to extend Activity in main class that extends "Fragment"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, switch-statement, navigation-drawer

I have an Android project and I use Navigation Drawer in it, and in the MainActivity, I have a switch-case, with options and your respective positions for to open when the user clicks. But, in a class called TelaQUEMSOMOS, the parameters that are there:

```
public class TelaQUEMSOMOS extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.telaquemsomos, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

are extending from Fragment and not Activity. It's bad, because I need to put a Toast.makeText or findViewById, and I can't. How can I handle it?

Link for download my project(the project is in portuguese): https://goo.gl/pm5dIC

Comment: Why not use 'getActivity()' from your Fragment?

Comment: And `rootView.findViewById()`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fragment you can call `getActivity()` to get instance of the activity.

Comment: Dont understand the downvote as getting activity is all OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below. First we will have an activity Home.java

```
final String[] fragments = {
        "com.locate.Establishment", "com.locate.Settings"};
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
DrawerLayout drawer;

public class Home extends Home {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
   .
   .//your other code here. 
   .
   // Here I am going to call the Fragment called Establishment
   FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(Home.this, fragments[0]));
   tx.commit();
   setToolbar(0);
 }
}
```

Implementation for Fragment. Here I am going to user support Fragment V4.

```
public class Establishment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_establishment, null);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
//Now will able to all you need here. By using getActivity().
}
}
```

Comment: someone is trolling, otherwise people usually inform why they downvote